# Limit of multivariable polynomial quotient

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm having trouble to solve this limit:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^3+3x^2y+7y^3}{2x^2+5y^2}$$

The answer is equal to 0 (zero) according to Wolfram Alpha. I tried to simplify the quotient, but no success. I tried to use the squeeze theorem too, but I am not certainty if this could be applied here. Could someone give me a hint?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that

$$0 \le \left| \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac {x^3+3x^2y+7y^3} {2x^2+5y^2} \right| = \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \left| \frac{x^3+3x^2y+7y^3} {2x^2+5y^2} \right| = \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \left| \frac{x^3+3x^2y} {2x^2+5y^2} + \frac{7y^3} {2x^2+5y^2}\right| \le \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \left| \frac{x^3+3x^2y} {2x^2+5y^2} \right| + \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \left| \frac{7y^3} {2x^2+5y^2}\right| \le \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \left| \frac{x^3+3x^2y} {2x^2} \right| + \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \left| \frac{7y^3} {5y^2}\right| = \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \left| \frac{x+3y} {2} \right| + \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \left| \frac{7y} {5}\right| = 0 ,$$

which shows that

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac {x^3+3x^2y+7y^3} {2x^2+5y^2} = 0 .$$

Comment: How can I infer that the initial limit is greater than or equal to zero? And I didn't understand the passage from the second to the third line; how {lim [(x^3+3x^2y)/(2x^2+5y^2)] + lim [7y^3/(2x^2+5y^2)]} becomes {lim [(x^3+3x^2y)/2x^2] + lim [7y^3/5y^2]}? More specifically, I didn't understand the transition of the denominators. Could you explain, please?

Comment: @AgnesKassahara: On the first line, that limit is enclosed in a modulus, and that is always positive. Concerning the denominators, when I remove $5y^2$ from $2x^2 + 5y^2$, the denominator becomes smaller (because it loses a positive quantity), so the whole fraction becomes larger.

Comment: A last question. In: $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \left| \frac{x^3+3x^2y} {2x^2+5y^2} + \frac{7y^3} {2x^2+5y^2}\right| \le \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \left| \frac{x^3+3x^2y} {2x^2+5y^2} \right| + \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \left| \frac{7y^3} {2x^2+5y^2}\right|$$ why less than or equal to?

Comment: @A.K.: Because, in general, $|x + y| \le |x| + |y|$. (Don't change your username, it creates confusion.)

Answer (score 0):

Set $x=r\cos\theta,\;y=r\sin\theta$. The rational function becomes
\begin{align}\
\Biggl\lvert\frac{x^3+3x^2y+7y^3}{2x^2+5y^2}\Biggr\rvert&=\frac{r^3\vert\cos^3\theta+3\cos^2\theta\sin\theta+7\sin^3\theta\rvert}{r^2(2\cos^2\theta+5\sin^2\theta)}
=r\,\frac{\lvert\cos^3\theta+3\cos^2\theta\sin\theta+7\sin^3\theta\rvert}{2+3\sin^2\theta}\le \frac32 r,
\end{align}
which shows the expression is as small as we wish as soon as $r$ is small enough.